# This program was supposed to save the product of each column of a two dimensional array in another one dimensional array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m, n, i, j, k;
    printf("Number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[m][n];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    { /*receiving each element as an input*/
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("Element a[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int p = 1;
    int v[n];

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) /*calcuclating the product of each column and 
                                  savin the value as the element of an array*/
        {
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                p *= a[i][j];
            }
            v[k] = p;
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[k]);
    }
```

The problem that I encounter is the calculation of the product for each column.I don't understand why the values get scattered and instead of calculating the product of each column it return a value taht is not correct.

The output looks like this:

```
Number of rows: 2
Number of columns: 2
Element a[1][1]
Element a[1][2]
Element a[2][1]
Element a[2][2]

2  4
3  6

144  20736
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems.  First you have an extra, unneeded loop when you are computing the product.  Second, you never reset the product when moving to a new column.

```
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        int p = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            p *= a[i][j];
        }
        v[j] = p;
    }
```